# Help identifying ESPN College Gameday promo ads font

Tags: font-identification

Is anyone familiar with the font used in ESPN College Gameday promotions? I have searched every well-known font identification service, and the closest match I have found is SF Collegiate. Examples can be found below:

[image: VIRGINA TECH]
[image: MICHIGAN ST OREGON]

I greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

It is the lowercase version of [College Bold](http://www.dafont.com/college.font?text=virgina).

[image]